# SELECT loop within SELECT loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP/MySQL scenario where I want to display a list of events but also show all users assigned to an event. In MySQL I have an `events`, `eventusers` and `users` tables.

I can `SELECT event_id, event_name FROM events` then loop through results in PHP and then `SELECT user_id FROM eventusers WHERE event=[event_id]` in each result loop to get that particular event's users.

I am wondering if there is way to do this in one single SQL query (and it's also performance decent) so I get data from the `events` table as well as all the user IDs attached to the event from the `eventusers` table. Something like:

```
event id | event name    | Users from eventusers table
------------------------------------------
1        | Soccer match  | 3,56,79
2        | Cycling       | 46,77,88,126,78
```

Comment: Sounds like a JOIN to me...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: This is not about joins. It is about being able to retrieve a list of results from a related table in each result row from the main table. I have improved the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of a JOIN statement, which merges your tables:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

In your case, you should do something like:

```
SELECT event_name, user
FROM events
INNER JOIN eventusers
ON events.event_id = eventusers.event_id
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Comment: Please see rephrased question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join function:

```
select * from
table1 JOIN table2
ON table1.pk=table2.fk
```

and then add the condition

```
where table1.column= something
```

however you need to have both tables joined with a column (.pk and .fk), in this case it could be the eventuserid

```
select * from
events JOIN eventusers
ON events.eventuserid=eventusers.userid
where event.id= [event_id]
```

Also you can subtitue the * with the columns you'll need: tablename.column and youll only get those column values in return

I'm sorry I dont understand the second part about the CSV file, can you clarify?